# Generating an EDM view from EF Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I've just made my database using Entity Framework Code First and everything is working great. However I want to see the schema of the entities; almost like generating an EDMX from the code first, but it doesn't have to do anything. 
How do I do this I hear there is a nuget package for it, but i'm not finding it. 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

The tool is called [Entity Framework PowerTools CTP 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx) and it is not NuGet package. It is standalone installer available on [VS Code Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d).

Comment: This is great! Thank you for your valuable input!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the **Code First** approach, you don't have *.edmx* schema/mapping files. The relationships between entities can be found within the POCO models themselves.

If you definitely want to use *.edmx* files, however, you can use the **Database First** approach. In that case, you would create your database manually and let the entity data model be automatically generated for you.

Comment: I understand all that, however it is much easier to work with other people in the design of the DB when there is a nice picture to look at. Also it's just another nice way to double check the model. Personal I don't like working with edmx, but I do like the visual layout for when the schema becomes large